# how to unit test a simple dart web app with dart:html

Tags: unit-testing, dart

I have a web app that uses `dart:html` and want to write a unit test.

I'm using WebStorm on Windows and want to be able to test something like this:

```
@TestOn("dartium")
import 'package:test/test.dart';
import 'package:web_app/foo.dart';


main(){
  test("test foo", _test_foo);
}

_test_foo(){
  var foo = new Foo();
  foo.addElement();
  foo.addTextToElement("hello");
  expect(foo.getTextFromElement(),"hello");
}
```

Now when I run `pub run test -pdartium` I get an error message like this:

```
Failed to load "test\foo_test.dart":
  Failed to run Dartium: The system cannot find the file specified.

    Command: dartium.exe --user-data-dir=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\dart_test_66df76b7-2dd7-11e8-83c1-cc3d825d91e7 http://localhost:65266/PmlVxFvYDEl8oBlmBmzs7uOKQlQWc51Y/packages/test/src/runner/browser/static/index.html?managerUrl=ws%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%
3A65266%2FPmlVxFvYDEl8oBlmBmzs7uOKQlQWc51Y%2F0&debug=false --disable-extensions --disable-popup-blocking --bwsi --no-first-run --no-default-browser-check --disable-default-apps --disable-translate.
```

Is there any documentation on how to do this properly?

Comment: What Dart version are you using? Dartium is deprecated and not part of Dart 2. If you're on Dart 1, `dartium.exe` might be missing. Either you installed the Dart SDK without Dartium (don't know if that is even provided without for Windows) or the path is not set to `dart-sdk/bin` and `pub test` can't find it.

Comment: I'm using 1.24.3 which I downloaded as a .zip from https://www.dartlang.org/install/archive

Comment: there is no dartium.exe in dart-sdk/bin. What is the recommended way to install dart on Windows?

Comment: It seems Dartium needs to be installed individually. https://www.dartlang.org/install/windows. You might want to consider Dart 2 with DDC and standard Chrome instead of Dartium but it's not well documented yet and no stable release yet.

Comment: Thanks Günter, Dart 2 is not yet an option, since were shipping for production. The Dartium for Windows only contains  `chrome.exe` and not `dartium.exe` that the test runner is looking for.

Comment: I'd just rename it, or create a copy

Comment: Ok, renaming it did the trick. Thanks @Günter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `chrome.exe` in `dart-sdk/bin` but no `dartium.exe` you can copy or rename `chrome.exe` to `dartium.exe`